# Can I use location/address of pointer as terminating condition in a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

So I understand that I can use the dereferenced value of a pointer as a condition in a for-loop. However, I've been trying to use the location of the pointer (within the array it's pointing at) as the terminating condition.

In other words, when the pointer iterates until the (say third) element of the array that it's pointing at, terminate the loop.

Here is my code below:

```
int main() {
    int *ptr = (int*) calloc(5, sizeof(int));
    //returns an int pointer pointing at {0, 0, 0, 0, 0} Correct??


    for (int i=0; ptr < ptr+3; ptr++, i++){     //i is for counting
        
        *ptr = i+1;     // dereference value of each element into 1
        printf("value of %d element of ptr is: %d \n", i, *ptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
value of 0 element of ptr is: 1
value of 1 element of ptr is: 1
value of 2 element of ptr is: 1
```

However, my code keeps running and outputting until it breaks when reaching a crazy high number (`value 1939010 of ptr is: 1939011`).

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding pointers or is the problem in my code

Comment: ptr will always be less than ptr + 3. Your test needs to be less than "initial value of ptr" + 3. It's also a very bad idea to mutate the only copy of the pointer to the memory that you allocated - how will you free it before ending your program? Instead, use a temporary variable, initialized to ptr.

Comment: You're not using the location of the pointer. You're using the value of the pointer.

Comment: You have incremented `ptr++` so now you won't be able to `free(ptr)`. Best to work with a copy of an allocated pointer if you are going to modify it.

Comment: A common idiom is: `for (int *p = ptr; p < ptr+3; p++){...`

Comment: @jarmod yup that makes perfect sense and I fixed it now. But also, if I terminate the loop using ptr < ptr + 18, the loop keeps going for 18 iterations. how come that happens if the pointer is only 5 elements long (as specified in calloc() )?

Comment: If I understand your question ... because you asked it to iterate 18 times. The for loop condition doesn't know how many elements you allocated earlier using calloc. It iterates exactly the number of times you asked it to, whether that's fewer or more than the actual number of elements.

Comment: @jarmod should it not return an out of bound error?

Comment: What it will do is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). C, unlike Java, does not have array index out of bounds checking.

Comment: Rule #1 of C programming: don't do really strange things just for the heck of it. There exists no reason why you can't have a loop counter here. `for(int i=0; i<3; i++) { ptr[i] = ...; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This for loop

```
for (int i=0; ptr < ptr+3; ptr++, i++){     //i is for counting
    
    *ptr = i+1;     // dereference value of each element into 1
    printf("value of %d element of ptr is: %d \n", i, *ptr);
}
```

is incorrect because it invokes undefined behavior.:) The expression `ptr` is evidently less than the expression `ptr + 3`.

What you need is the following

```
int i = 0;
for ( int *p = ptr; p < ptr+3; p++ ){     //i is for counting
    
    *p = ++i;     // dereference value of each element into 1
    printf("value of %d element of p is: %d \n", i - 1, *p);
}
```

That is you need to introduce a new variable of the pointer type that will be incremented in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense and fixed it now. But also, if I terminate the loop using ptr < ptr + 18, the loop keeps going for 18 iterations. how come that happens if the pointer is only 5 elements long (as specified in calloc() )?

Comment: @MahmoudGabr It seems you mean p < ptr + 18. This just means undefined behavior: accessing memory beyond the allocated array.

Comment: But should it not return an error instead of looping the 18 times? sorry if questions are a bit naive

Comment: @MahmoudGabr The compiler does not check array bounds at compile time.